# Echo only the sessions profile picture instead of the entire databases pictures

Tags: php, database, session, echo

Right now my code is echoing all of the users and their profile picture in a database. My goal is to echo only the session username and profile picture. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php

        $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            echo $username['username'];
                        if($row['image'] == ""){
                            echo "<img width='100 height='100' src='/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/ao.jpg' alt ='Default Profile Pic'>";

                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/".$row['image']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";
                        }
                    echo "<br>";    
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: It sounds like you only want to show the current user so add a `WHERE` clause to your `SELECT * FROM users`.

Comment: `$username` where you defined this?

Comment: TRY: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username['username']."'"`

Comment: The username is defined as ```$username = $_SESSION['username'];``` and the code you added gave me this error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in /home/benrud/public_html/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/account.php on line 34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, than you have to add a WHERE clause to your SQL array. I think the variable `$username` is already defined and is an array with the data of the current User. Also I assume that the table-column for the username is named "username". So your way to a working solution is might be this:

```
<?php

    $q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username['username']."' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        echo $username['username'];
                    if($row['image'] == ""){
                        echo "<img width='100 height='100' src='/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/ao.jpg' alt ='Default Profile Pic'>";

                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<img width='100' height='100' src='/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/images/".$row['image']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";
                    }
                echo "<br>";    
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I got this error from that: Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in /home/benrud/public_html/student/globalit/2019/GamerMedia/pages/account.php on line 34

Comment: Did you checked the right enclousre to the sql Query username= ' " . $username['username'] ." '